# Unable to download Simulators for XCode 13.2.1

Tags: xcode

The components panel for XCode 13.2.1 shows no simulators.  When starting the debugger, only IOS version 15.2 is available for simulation.  How do I download simulators for earlier versions of IOS on XCode 13.2.1 (also I'm on Mac OS 12.1)?